# Can't delete previous comment

Tags: bug, comment

Please see my comment [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187564/stochastic-volatility-and-sdes#comment358903_187564). I am unable to delete it since the X used to delete it overlaps with the Related question links:

[image]

Is there any way that I can delete the comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways...

1. You can flag it and ask us diamond-mods to delete
2. You can disable MathJax, delete and then enable MathJax.

---

You may also find the formatting sandbox in meta.math.stackexchange to be useful when typing complex mathematics for a comment.

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox